# Displaying the text in center on banner images in all mobile devices

Tags: html, css

```css
  @media only screen and (max-device-width: 667px) and (min-device-width: 375px){
    .eventspage{
     background: transparent url(http://www.server.com/blue/image.jpg) center center/contain no-repeat scroll;}
    .eventspagetitle {
    margin-top: -226px !important;
 font-size:18px;
    }
    }
    .eventspagetitle {
    position: fixed;
    right: 14%;
    top: 65%;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 568px) and (min-device-width: 320px)
    .eventspagetitle {
     right: 8%;
     }
```

```html
    <section class="page-bnr eventspage">
    <div class="title-wrap ">
 <h5 class="eventspagetitle">Momentous events around the corner.</h5>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Added banner images with text on it.Images are getting mobile responsive but the text is not getting aligned in center for the banner images.In any mobile devices the text should be aligned in center of the image.Here is the code which i have added.

```
<section class="page-bnr eventspage">
<div class="title-wrap ">
<h5 class="eventspagetitle">Momentous events around the corner.</h5>
</div>
</section>

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 667px) and (min-device-width: 375px){
.eventspage{
 background: transparent url(http://www.server.com/blue/image.jpg) center center/contain no-repeat scroll;}
.eventspagetitle {
margin-top: -226px !important;
font-size:18px;
}
}
.eventspagetitle {
position: fixed;
right: 14%;
top: 65%;
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 568px) and (min-device-width: 320px)
.eventspagetitle {
 right: 8%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving your element a position of fixed. This is causing it to remain in the position you initially set. The top and right values are going to remain constant and may not work on smaller devices.

You can center the text with the code below. This will allow you to resize the browser/device and keep the text centered to you relative element (`.title-wrap`).

Try adding this css:

```
.title-wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.eventspagetitle {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 667px) and (min-device-width: 375px) {
  .eventspage {
    background: transparent url(http://www.server.com/blue/image.jpg) center center/contain no-repeat scroll;
  }
  .title-wrap {
    position: relative;
  }
  .eventspagetitle {
    margin-top: -226px !important;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

.eventspagetitle {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

```html
<section class="page-bnr eventspage">
  <div class="title-wrap ">
    <h5 class="eventspagetitle">Momentous events around the corner.</h5>
  </div>
</section>
```

Bookmark this: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

I always return to it if I forget/need a refresher.

Comment: in iphone 5 and iphone x it is not displaying correctly

Comment: i mean to say in all mobile devices the text is not displaying at the center on the banner image